# Understanding cancelParent function in coroutines

Tags: kotlin, parent-child, kotlin-coroutines

I was reading some source code on coroutines and run into this function;

```
private fun cancelParent(cause: Throwable): Boolean {
    // CancellationException is considered "normal" and parent is not cancelled when child produces it.
    // This allow parent to cancel its children (normally) without being cancelled itself, unless
    // child crashes and produce some other exception during its completion.
    if (cause is CancellationException) return true
    if (!cancelsParent) return false
    return parentHandle?.childCancelled(cause) == true
}
```

The point that I don't quite get is the very first line of code. It feels like it contradicts with what's stated in the comment. If the exception is `CancellationException` then it's a "normal" cancellation and the parent should not be cancelled, right? However, the function returns `true` which is read like - "Ok, I'm gonna cancel the parent".

By the way, the rest of the lines/checks in the function make sense to me when I look into what, for example `supervisorScope` or `launch`, returns.

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's one of the cases where naming return values would be valuable.

If you look at the [usage of this code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/0d7f3fbef9b5ccb4972bcd6b974c487581431fcd/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/JobSupport.kt#L226), you'll see the following:

```
// Now handle the final exception
if (finalException != null) {
    val handled = cancelParent(finalException) || handleJobException(finalException)
    if (handled) (finalState as CompletedExceptionally).makeHandled()
}
```

So, `true` means not `shouldParentBeCancelled?`, as one may assume, but `wasCancellationAlreadyHandledOrShouldBeHandledByParent?`

Comment: I think this (never) version in the link makes it more clear.